check to see if .h exists via makefile
I am effectively trying to emulate cmake's check_include_file in a regular Makefile.
Say for example I want to check to make sure stdint.h is on the users system when compiling a project so that I can pass in a flag like -DHAVE_STDINT when compiling. I know how to pass the flag when compiling, I am mainly concerned about how I can find the file. What is the best way to do this in a Makefile, if it can be done at all?

Are you talking about POSIX-conforming makefiles?  Or a specific implementation such as GNU Make?

CMake is not analogous to make.  A "regular makefile" has entirely different significance from inputs to CMake.  The kind of thing you're asking about is far and away better handled outside of make -- by CMake, perhaps, or by an Autotools configure script, or by one of several other alternatives.

@MadScientist I'd be interested in reading solutions for both if possible, however, I am using GNU make on my main system

@JohnBollinger I understand that cmake is not analogous to make. I was just curious if something similar could be done using a shell script or something in the Makefile so i can pass a flag when compiling smaller projects that don't really require a whole build system generator like cmake

That would be quite a bit of shell scripting within the makefile (or adjunct to it) in order to do this.  You need to create a small C program with the include, see if it compiles (this is the best way to check, existence of an include file does not mean it is usable), then depending on the result create the define.   Easier to use an existing system (autoconf, cmake, perl's dist, mkconfig (I wrote, no longer supporting)).

You can certainly write a script that does those determinations, and integrate it with a makefile such that the script's outputs are somehow or other fed back to make. And that would be categorically worse than putting a similar script in front of make.  Harder to write, harder to maintain, more brittle, with no appreciable upside.

There's probably no good way to do it in POSIX-conforming makefiles.  The POSIX definition of make is extremely anemic and has very limited functionality.  You could do it with GNU Make depending on exactly what you want and need.  For example, it's trivial to determine if the file /usr/include/stdint.h exists on the system.  But most likely you're really looking for something more sophisticated similar to John's description.  That's what GNU's autotools are for (or, something like cmake).

In my experience everyone who says "but I don't want all that complicated stuff" and tries to roll their own "simple" version, eventually ends up with either something ad hoc that checks for a very small number of very specific environments, or else something that grows to be just as complicated, and nowhere near as standard, as the tools they're trying to avoid.

What are you going to do if make can't find the header file?  Fail the compile?  That gains you nothing over the compiler failing because it couldn't find the header.

Which platforms don't have stdint.h?  It's a c99 feature.  The way to do, btw, is like autotools to generate a program that will fail if the header is missing.  That way you use the compiler search paths etc.  Otherwise it ends being an a/b problem where you may check if the path exist but you really want to check if the compiler can find it.

@AllanWind I just used stdint.h as a simple example

The #define HAVE_* 1, such as #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1 in a config.h file are exactly what autoconf et. al. do.
